# GooglePlayServices's api isUserResolvableError return true also when is not a resolvable error?

Tags: android, google-play-services, harmonyos

At starting of my app I check if there are the playservices.
To complete the job I wrote a code like the following:

```
private fun checkPlayServices(): Boolean {
    val apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()
    val resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                    .show()
        } else {
            //show my custom error message
        }
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

The issue is that the method isUserResolvableError return true also when the error code is SERVICE_INVALID and in this way my custom error message is being never showed .

Why ? I'm doing it in wrong way ?

EDIT: I test it on HarmonyOs OS

Answer (score 1):

The code referred is based on Google’s design, HarmonyOS does not control the outcome of true or false of this check.

Answer (score 0):

According to the team, HarmonyOS does not currently support APIs related to GoogleApiAvailability. Please stay tuned on HarmonyOS official websites.